# Can you exclude a source file from CPD check?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am using the `maven-pmd-plugin` in my project. When I build the project, I am getting duplicate (due to java constructor code) code error during `cpd-check`. How do I exclude specific java files from CPD check?

Answer (score 3):

Add an `excludeFromFailure` file in `cpd-check` goal configuration in your `pom.xml`:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>cpd-check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <excludeFromFailureFile>exclude-cpd.properties</excludeFromFailureFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The `exclude-cpd.properties` file must contain the full class name.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-pmd-plugin-3.6/examples/violation-exclusions.html